# google translate select menu indexing problem - how to automatically select language to translate to?

Tags: javascript, arrays, select, google-translate

I'm trying to have a translation automatically occur when a page is loaded using Google Translate's Library following the instructions from this link: https://orangeable.com/javascript/google-translate

The code below creates a select menu through Google Translate and then the JS should be getting that select menu and changing its selection to the given language, but the statement to get the select menu itself is faulty.

> 

```
  <script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
  
  <div id="google_translate_element"></div>

  <div class=to-translate>text to be translated</div>

  <div class="notranslate">this text will not be translated</div>

  <script>
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement(
            {
                pageLanguage: "en"
            },
            "google_translate_element"
        );
    }
    var lang = "fr";
    const select = document.getElementsByClassName('goog-te-combo');
    console.log(select, select[0], select.length);    
    select[0].value = lang;
```

I've been trying the included log statement and other variations - it produces an HTML Collection and then indexing it is undefined?
I think I'm not indexing it correctly somehow but I don't even know what to look up to figure it out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was able to accomplish my goal of automatically translating my website with

```
window.location = ("https://websitedomain/#googtrans(en|" + lang + ")");
```

but I am still curious about why the previous attempt did not work!